# Linux boot issue

Tags: linux, boot, debian, parrot-os

I get this text:
[sdb] no caching node page found

[sdb] assuming drive cache: write though.

wrong diagnostic page : asked for 1 got 8.

Failed to get diagnostic page 0x1.

Failed to bind enclosure -19

Comment: Please [do not cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

Comment: Sounds like grub is pointing to the wrong disk/partition.